# What does 'deferred substitution' mean?

Tags: parsing, haskell, interpreter

I'm writing a simple parser/interpreter for a [language](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps112/Winter07/hw/extended-interpreters.shtml). The instructions keep mentioning 'deferred substitution', as in

> Extend the `fun` language feature described so that functions
>   can accept a list of zero or more arguments instead of just one. All
>   arguments to the function must evaluate with the same deferred
>   substitutions.

I don't need any help with implementing this, I'm just confused about what 'deferred substitution' means. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would take a closer look at chapter 5 and section 6.4 in [the textbook you seem to be using](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/PDF/plai-2006-01-15.pdf).

Comment: The link I provided was just something I googled quickly... It's not my assignment, but thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deferred substitution refers to the practice of substituting the values of variables at the latest step possible. By doing so, you are deferring the substitution of it!

Here's an example that might help you understand what it means:
Suppose that you have the following function:
f(x) = 500 + 300 + 2x + 45x

Let's say that x = 1
If you want to defer the substitution of x, you would probably do:

1. f(x) = 800 + 2x + 45x
2. f(x) = 800 + 47x
3. f(1) = 800 + 47(1)

Notice that we have substituted the values of x at the latest step possible, after simplifying everything that is not a variable in this function.